# Slider Buttons that Hide and Reveal CSS Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for Javascript code that enables a user alternately to click a button to fully display an unordered list and click another to hide all but the first element of the list.  By default overflowed content is hidden owing to the styling of the unordered list.  I'm hoping to achieve a result similar to the `-webkit-paged-x` except without a vertical or horizontal scrollbar appearing.

```css
ul{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:20px; 
  width: 20px;
}
li{
  float:left;
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="<"><input type="button" value=">">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I think it would be a shame to close this question.  Sometimes a person just needs a little help to learn how to learn.  I and another individual have found it worth our while to try to help out the OP.  Please don't spoil what should prove to be a good educational experience for all concerned.

Comment: @slevy SO is not a platform for tutorials or writing code for users. You need to read the Help Center.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for reminding me about the Help Center.  I esp. like the section that states: "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't.". The OP is evidently a new user and I think he should be cut some slack.

Comment: @slevy So I pointed out the rules to him and that does not change the rule that he is required to write his own code and post his code here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following snippet will work. When clicking the right arrow button the overflow will show with no scroll; when clicking the left arrow button the content inside the list element will return to `overflow:hidden`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('input').attr('type','button').click(function(){
    $('ul').css( 'overflow', 'hidden');
  });
  
  $('input').attr('type','button').next().click(function(){
    $('ul').css( 'overflow', 'visible');
  });
  
});
```

```css
ul{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:20px; 
  width: 20px;
}
li{
  float:left;
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="<"><input type="button" value=">">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Revised Answer

In this revised version, the code is simpler in many respects.  First, it simplifies the HTML so that there is a toggle button that slides the list elements down and up.  Also, the code embellishes the CSS to emphasize the slide effect. Incidentally, the code uses a customized bullet.

I've simplified the JavaScript so that it merely changes the class name of the unordered list to toggle between its full and partial displays.  Note: the CSS does not alter the overflow property; it remains hidden.  Instead, it changes the height property of the list, so that when only one element displays, the list style "close" reflects a height of 20px but when the list slides down, its style is now "open" and has a height of 120px.

```js
var d = document;

var ul_tag = d.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var btn    = d.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
       if ( ul_tag.className == "close") {
        ul_tag.className = "open";
       }
       else
       if (ul_tag.className == "open") {
        ul_tag.className = "close";
       }
};
```

```css
ul {
background:#ffdede;
  border: 3px dotted #cff;
  box-shadow:3px 3px 6px #777;
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

ul.close{
  height:20px; 
  width: 20px;
}

ul.open{
  height:120px; 
  width: 20px;
}


li{
  float:left;
  width:30px;
  color:#306;
  font: 1em Helvetica;
}

button {
 background:#000;
 color:cyan;
 margin-left:23px;
 border:none;
}

ul li:before {
margin-left:-20px;
 color: #f0f;
 content: '» ';
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button title="Click to Toggle List">&hearts;</button>
  <ul class="close">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```